# IOS:UISerachBar Filter name but not the related id with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have a `JSON` `Dict` in this format

```
{
  "382" : "sudhir kumar",
  "268" : "David  ",
  "385" : "aayush test",
  "261" : "Mike watson",
  "277" : "TestDrivers Driver",
  "381" : "sudhir kumar",
  "380" : "sudhir kumar",
  "383" : "asdfgh asdfgh",
  "376" : " "
}
```

I have to display it in UISearchBar. Someone please help me to solve it as when i select any name from search its respective Id also selected

I am using the following code it filtered name but not their related ID's with name

**My code is:**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;
{
    tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:DriverNameArray];
    //NSString *stringToSearch = textField.text;

    tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:DriverIdArray];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",searchText]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate

    //NSPredicate * predicateid = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",stringToSearch];

    NSArray *tempresults = [DriverNameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (tempresults.count > 0)
    {
        tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults];
        tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults];
    }
    [SEarchTable reloadData];
    //return  YES;
}
```

It always returns the same id for all the filtered names

Answer (score 0):

Create `NSarray` of `NSdictionary` containing id and name

```
MasterArray :

(
 0{ id = "382" , drivername = "sudhir kumar"}
 1{ id = "383" , drivername = "sudha mishra"}
.
.
 n{ id = "384" , drivername = "sudesh pandit"}
)
```

whatever search result you will get in Your `DriverNameArray`. Iterate for loop through that and compare driver name with `MasterArray`
:

```
for(i = 0; i< DriverNameArray.count , i++)
{
    //take driver name from search result array
    NSString * driverName = [DriverNameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    for(j = 0; j< MasterArray.count , j++){// search driver name in MasterArray
        NSDictionary *driverInfoDic = [MasterArray objectAtIndex:j];
        if(driverName isEqualToString:[driverInfoDic objectForKey:@"drivername"])
            NSString *driverId = [driverInfoDic objectForKey:@"Id"];//use this driver id by storing it in DiverIdArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering only Drivers' names  array, which is not primarily connected with Drivers' ids array. I suggest you joining id, and name into a dictionary and storing it in one array. So that, whenever you filter it with name, or id the rest info will be stored in one object

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allElements
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *filteredArray;
```

`

```
  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) { //Just simple example
        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name": DriverNameArray[i], @"id": DriverIdArray[i] };
        [self.allElements addObject:dictionary];

    }
```

And in your searchbar delegate you can use:

```
NSArray *copyArray = [self.allElements copy];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH %@", searchText];

NSArray *filteredArray = [copyArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


self.filteredArray = filteredArray;

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: it return null filtered array